# Sharing a image URL and text in LinkedIn integration using sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api

In LinkedIn sharing,LinkedIn provide a SDK but using this SDK,I can't share image link and text it always shows

> LISDKErrorAPIDomain Code=403 The operation couldn’t be completed. (LISDKErrorAPIDomain error 403.)

Code:

```
NSString *url = @"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares";
NSString *payload = @"{\"comment\":\"Check out developer.linkedin.com! http://linkd.in/1FC2PyG\",\"visibility\":{ \"code\":\"anyone\" }}";

if ([LISDKSessionManager hasValidSession])

{

     [[LISDKAPIHelper sharedInstance] postRequest:url stringBody:payload
                                         success:^(LISDKAPIResponse *response) {
                                             // do something with response

                                             NSLog(@"response : %@",response.data);
                                         }
                                           error:^(LISDKAPIError *apiError) {
                                               // do something with error
                                               NSLog(@"error: %@",apiError);
                                           }];
}
```

Comment: Adding your code which is use.

Comment: Have you followed the rest of the steps in https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk?  a 403 error suggests that you are not using a valid consumer key/secret combo that the API server can identify you with.

Comment: i have use a valid consumer & secret key.

Comment: Just resolved by asking permissions for LISDK_W_SHARE_PERMISSION

Answer (score 0):

Sharing on LinkedIn Error : LISDKErrorAPIDomain Code=403 The operation couldn’t be completed.

if you are repeating same static text to post on LinkedIn, it might be a change to getting same error.

Answer (score -1):

you must get share permission before add post

```
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION,LISDK_W_SHARE_PERMISSION, nil];
```

full login code

```
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION,LISDK_W_SHARE_PERMISSION, nil];

    [LISDKSessionManager createSessionWithAuth:permissions state:nil showGoToAppStoreDialog:YES successBlock:^(NSString *returnState){
        NSLog(@"%s","success called!");
        LISDKSession *session = [[LISDKSessionManager sharedInstance] session];
        NSLog(@"Session  : %@", session.description);

        [[LISDKAPIHelper sharedInstance] getRequest:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~"
                                            success:^(LISDKAPIResponse *response) {

                                                NSData* data = [response.data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                NSDictionary *dictResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

                                                NSString *authUsername = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", [dictResponse valueForKey: @"firstName"], [dictResponse valueForKey: @"lastName"]];
                                                NSLog(@"Authenticated user name  : %@", authUsername);


                                            } error:^(LISDKAPIError *apiError) {
                                                NSLog(@"Error  : %@", apiError);
                                            }];
    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error called  : %@", error);
    }];
```